# Foundry expectRevert on Custom Error with Multiple Errors

Tags: solidity, error, foundry, custom-errors, forge

I am attempting to `expectRevert` on a custom error with MULTIPLE parameters by following the example in the office Foundry. I am able to get it to work with a single parameter. But as soon as I add a second parameter to the custom error I get an error in the `forge test` runner.

https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/expect-revert

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue? Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Contract

```
error MaximumContributionExceeded(uint256 isIndividual, uint256 temp);
...
revert MaximumContributionExceeded({isIndividual: 1, temp: 2});
```

Test (Foundry Test Contract)

```
bytes4 selector = bytes4(keccak256("MaximumContributionExceeded(uint256, uint256)"));
vm.expectRevert(abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, 1, 2));
ico.contribute{value: 1501 ether}();
```

Error

```
[FAIL. Reason: Error != expected error: 0xd38ddc2300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002 != 0x1d3d86b7]
```

Full code
https://gist.github.com/bd9b4964bc96e88cb6da5a2d59e5672c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to remove the space between `uint256` and `uint256` on this line: `bytes4 selector = bytes4(keccak256("MaximumContributionExceeded(uint256,uint256)"));`

Comment: Very nice! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While the [selected answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/147047/126222) by [currenthandle](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/28407/currenthandle) should fix your issue, I would suggest programmatically using the error selector.

```
vm.expectRevert(MyContract.MaximumContributionExceeded.selector, 1, 2)
```